# Como poner al text de un Textfield en un List el valor de un String de un Viewmodel en SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo el siguiente View en SwiftUI y lo que quiero es crear un Textfield con el valor del name el cual es una propiedad del Model pero no he podido hacerlo , este es el código:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
        @StateObject  private var vm = ContentViewModel()
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView{
                ForEach(vm.models){model in
                    HStack{
                        Text(model.description)
                        Text(model.name)
                        TextField("title", text:model.name)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

extension ContentView{
    @MainActor class ContentViewModel:ObservableObject{
        @Published var models:[Model]=[]
        
        init() {
            self.models = createSomeData()
        }
        
        func showData(){
            for model in models{
                print(model.description)
            }
        }
        
        func createSomeData()->[Model]{
            var local=[Model]()
            let model=Model()
            model.id=UUID()
            model.name="nombre"
            model.description="xbox"
            
            local.append(model)
            
            return local
        }
    }
}


class Model:Identifiable{
    var id:UUID=UUID()
    var name:String=""
    var description:String=""
}
```

El error que me tira es este : Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando permites que el usuario modifique los datos en la interfaz, en este caso un `TextField`, debes tomar en cuenta los **bindings**. Esto permite que los datos de tu modelo se actualicen automáticamente y para eso se utiliza el símbolo `$`.

Los cambios en tu código son con la variable `vm` que es de tipo `ObservableObject`:

```
$vm.models
```

También hacemos un binding del modelo:

```
{ $model in
```

Y finalmente agregamos el valor en el `TextField`:

```
TextField("title", text: $model.name)
```

El código modificado:

```
ForEach($vm.models){ $model in
            HStack{
                Text(model.description)
                Text(model.name)
                TextField("title", text: $model.name)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente!! gracias.